# Retain original \- (discretionary hyphen) in all babel languages

Tags: babel, hyphenation, languages

In `babel`-less LaTeX `\-` will add a discretionary hyphen making this the only allowed break-point of the word. This is also the behaviour in *most* `babel`-languages, but some, e.g. Danish and Dutch, redefine `\-` to only adding *further* hyphenation-points to the ones already provided. This is unfortunate imo (took me quite a while to figure out why my `\-`s didn't work any more...) and becomes cumbersome when proofing multi-language books, a process that often involves correcting wrong or undesired hyphenations by specifically providing correct ones.

Redefining `\-` to `\babelhyphen*{soft}` works but will be reset by the next language-switch. How could I get *all* languages to display the standard behaviour for `\-` once and for all in the preamble?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}

\usepackage{showhyphens} %needs LuaTeX

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{danish}
\renewcommand{\-}{\babelhyphen*{soft}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit  Morbi princip\-erklæring  ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis.


\selectlanguage{english}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit  Morbi princip\-erklæring  ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis.

\selectlanguage{danish}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit  Morbi princip\-erklæring  ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addto\extrasdanish{\renewcommand{\-}{\babelhyphen*{soft}}}`

Comment: Great! (I had fiddled around with the shorthand-commands but didn't think of extras) Is there something like "extrasall", just to be sure that I cover all languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hook in `babel` executed after every `\extras<lang>`:

```
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}

\AddBabelHook{softhyphen}{afterextras}
  {\renewcommand{\-}{\babelhyphen*{soft}}}

\usepackage{showhyphens} %needs LuaTeX
```

Here `softhyphen` is just a name to label the hook (you can change it), and `afterextras` is the point where the code is executed (self-explanatory, I think).